# how do i create 3d model of a room using lenovo phab 2 pro?

Tags: google-project-tango

i am a new user of lenovo phab 2 pro and i want to create a 3d model of my room and save it.i have tried some apps but they did not work for me. Please suggest me  some good apps for this .

Answer (score 0):

Tango's own [Constructor](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.projecttango.constructor&hl=en_GB) app works well

Answer (score 0):

It is possible with [RTAB-Map](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.introlab.rtabmap&hl=en).